# What is the scope of grunt config property?

Tags: gruntjs, grunt-contrib-watch

We have a grunt task ([*grunt-svninfo*](https://github.com/liqweed/grunt-svninfo)) that saves config property to be used later by other tasks.

So for example, if we run *grunt-postcss* after that task, it can access that config property and extract info from it.

But, if we run *grunt-contrib-watch* after that task, so when it detect change in *.less files it will invoke *grunt-postcss* and the config property is no longer exists (undefined).

Why aren't config properties (or global variables) reachable from within tasks invokes from the *grunt-contrib-watch* task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*grunt-contrib-watch* has an option to [spawn](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-watch#optionsspawn) tasks in new process.

The default is *'true'*, so subsequent task doesn't share the same context (config properties \ global variables).

Setting it to 'false' solve the problem for us.